# minimal sets in a subset of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{X})$ and a set $A\in \wp(X)$ does there exist  a least set $B\in \mathcal{X}$ such that $A \subseteq B$ ?

**def.** *a measurable space* $(X,\mathcal{X})$ consists of a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. a non-empty set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \wp(X)$ which is closed under countable union and complements.

Comment: So $A$ is a family of subsets of $X$, $B$ is a subset of $X$ and $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Sorry about that I mixed up two notations, it should either have been $A \subseteq X$ or $A \in \wp(X)$ -I've corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, $\mathcal{X}$ the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ that are countable or have a countable complement. If $A$ is an uncountable subset of $X$ with an uncountable complement, there is no such $B$. If $B$ would be a measurable superset of $A$, $B$ would have a countable complement (it clearly cannot be countable) and therefore $B\setminus A$ would contain some point $x$. Then $A\subseteq B\setminus\{x\}\subset B$, so $B$ is not minimal.

Maybe more natural: If $A$ is not Lebesgue measurable, there exists no Lebesgue measurable minimal superset. For if $B$ is a Lebesgue measurable superset of $A$, we must have $A\subseteq B$ and $A\neq B$. So $B \setminus A$ must contain a real number $x$. Now $B\setminus\{x\}$ is measurable too, so $A\neq B\setminus\{x\}\subset B$, showing again that $B$ is not minimal.

Indeed, the argument works whenever some set is not measurable and the $\sigma$-algebra contains all singletons.

Comment: Hmm .. I see where you are going .. how do I know that there exists such a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: You mean the countable co-countable $\sigma$-algebra? That is just a straightforward exercise using the fact that the countable union of countable sets is again a countable set.

Comment: thank you very much! it was a super clarifying answer :)